# Label printer not printing correctly starts from the begining instead of the end

Tags: c#

I have the following code, but its printing from the start of the label and trying to print forward when it should start from the end of the label and print forward.. I have an image below for reference, I have looked on stackoverflow for similar questions but no luck. Thank you for your time and efforts to help me.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
    }
    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
        {
            var width = 2.44 * 100;
            var height = 100;
            var s = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", (int)width, (int)height);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = s;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            pd.DocumentName = "Label";
            pd.OriginAtMargins = true;
            pd.PrintPage += Pd_PrintPage;
            pd.Print();
        }
    }
    private void Pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 60);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(LabelPreview.Buffer.Text, drawFont, drawBrush, 0, 0, drawFormat);
    }
    protected void OnButton1Released(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Print();
    }
}
```

Here is the image

[image: Printing from front instead of back]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add `pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);` after `pd.OriginAtMargins = true;`.

The default value of `pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins` is 1-inch margins on all sides.

Comment: I added the line you requested but still having the same issue, there is about 3 inches of space before that print.

Comment: @LevonRavel Then please check the Matrix `e.Graphics.Transform` before `e.Graphics.DrawString`